# OpenGL - error during compilation

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Recently I started trying to work with OpenGL on linux (before writing under android, using OpenGL ES 2.0), but I encountered the impossibility of compiling the project. Here is what the compiler provides:

```
    g++ main.cpp -o main -lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): неопределённая ссылка на символ «dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5»
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To compile application on the command line, I use the following linker options:-lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread

The OpenGL code (picked up specifically from the source where everything works):

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Shaders
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    // Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    //GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //  // First triangle
    //   0.5f,  0.5f,  // Top Right
    //   0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Right
    //  -0.5f,  0.5f,  // Top Left
    //  // Second triangle
    //   0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Right
    //  -0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Left
    //  -0.5f,  0.5f   // Top Left
    //};
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // Top Left
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // First Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // Second Triangle
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO


    // Uncommenting this call will result in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw our first triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It would help if you used the "C" locale to get non-localized compiler messages that you could throw at a websearch, too. However, I'm guessing that this is missing `-ldl`. In any case, please read the site guidelines concerning minimal example code, your's isn't minimal.

Comment: Not an expert, but this may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/521706/error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line-while-compiling-g13-driver

Comment: I added -ldl, but the problem remained: g ++ main.cpp -o main -lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXrandr -lXi -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): Undefined reference to the symbol "XConvertSelection"
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `g++ main.cpp \`pkg-config --libs glfw3 glew\`` works fine for me on  Debian Stretch after installing `libglfw3-dev` and `libglew-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was

```
pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3
```

To get the packages I need for them to run and in the right order.

Then I run

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lXi -lGLEW -lGLU -lm -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -ldrm -lXdamage -lX11-xcb -lxcb-glx -lxcb-dri2 -lglfw3 -lrt -lm -ldl -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXxf86vm -lXext -lXcursor -lXrender -lXfixes -lX11 -lpthread -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp
```

and the project successfully compiled

Comment: Note: `pkg-config --static --libs glew glfw3`
Quite enough